# Equivalence relation between measures $\nu$, $\mu$ is equivalent to $\nu = f \mu$ for a density $f$.

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I'm working on an exercise that wants me to show that for $\sigma$-finite measures $\nu$ and $\mu$ the relation $\nu \sim \mu$ (defined by $\nu \ll \mu$ and $\mu \ll \nu$) is equivalent to $\nu = f \mu$ for a density $f$ which satisfies $0 < f(\omega) < + \infty$ for $\mu$-almost all $\omega \in \Omega$.

I can show almost everything, but I cannot show $\mu \ll \nu$ just by assuming $\nu = f \mu$. I'm almost starting to wonder whether there is not a fault in the exercise perhaps. If someone could give me some tips on where I'm going wrong that would be fanastic!

What I've done so far:

$(\nu \sim \mu \Rightarrow \nu = f \mu)$:
This is simply an application of Radon-Nikodym and we thus see that $\nu = f \mu$. Since $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, $f$ takes real values $\mu$-almost everywhere.

$( \nu = f \mu \Rightarrow \nu \sim \mu)$:
Again use Radon-Nikdym, but now the other way around. Then $\nu \ll \mu$.

For $\mu \ll \nu$ I don't know what to do. It tried splitting it into $\mu = \mu_s + \mu_c$ where $\mu_s \ll \nu$, but I don't know how to show that $\mu_c = 0$, so I don't think that is the right direction...

Thank you very much for any hint you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're there. Note that $\mu = {1 \over f} \nu$, and $0 < 1/f < + \infty$ a.e. Therefore $\mu \ll \nu$ by what you've already done.

Comment: That is.. easier than I thought. Can I just assume without proving that $\frac{1}{f}$ exists then?

Comment: I guess after thinking about it that since $0 < 1/f < + \infty$ that is enough to assume existance. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Well, ${1 \over f}$ exists since $f$ is never 0. You have, for $E$ measurable, $\mu(E)=\int \chi_E d\mu = \int \chi_E {f \over f} d\mu = \int \chi_E {1 \over f} d\nu$, which shows that $1 \over f$ is the density you want.